# HAWQ installation error

Tags: compiler-errors, installation, hawq

I am not able to install Hawq even after following the steps on HAWQ website , 
for reference : https://github.com/apache/incubator-hawq

I am getting this error when i run :
./configure --without-readline

```
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.h usability... no
checking thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.h presence... yes
configure: WARNING: thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.h: present but cannot be compiled
configure: WARNING: thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.h:     check for missing prerequisite headers?
configure: WARNING: thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.h: see the Autoconf documentation
configure: WARNING: thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
configure: WARNING: thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
configure: WARNING:     ## --------------------------------------------------------- ##
configure: WARNING:     ## Report this to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HAWQ ##
configure: WARNING:     ## --------------------------------------------------------- ##
checking for thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.h... no
configure: error: thrift is required
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: The error message states "thrift is required"... so you're probably missing that

Comment: No, i can see thrift --version in there. Still it shows " thrift required "

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check if you have installed thrift, because there is an error message:"configure: error: thrift is required".
After installing it, make sure its path can be found.